# Unable to change the value of a variable across classes using methods

Tags: c#, variables, methods, game-development

I am trying to create a Terraria tModLoader mod that displays Combat rank based on the combo that player has and I have a problem with updating the texture of the UI. The system that counts player’s combo is in a separate class and stores the rank value in an int variable (variable *Rank*). It calculates this value using the *RankExchange* method, which is called at each tick of the game. This method then calls another method in the UIElement class where the UI texture changes according to the received value (variable *_rankID*). The problem is that I cannot, under any circumstances, change the value of the variable on which the UI texture depends using the method.

When I tried changing the *_rankID* value inside the *Update(GameTime gameTime)* void, everything worked normally and the UI was changing correctly (I used *_rankID--;* operator inside the *Update* void).

Why can't I change the value of a variable across classes using my custom methods?

ModPlayer class:

```
public class btPlayer : ModPlayer
{
        //Changing Rank value
        public void RankExchange(int Combo, bool Announcer)
        {
            if (Combo < 170)
            {
                Rank = 0;
            }
            else if (Combo < 300)
            {
                Rank = 1;
            }
            else if (Combo < 500)
            {
                Rank = 2;
            }
            else if (Combo < 1000)
            {
                Rank = 3;
            }
            else if (Combo < 2000)
            {
                Rank = 4;
            }
            else if (Combo < 3500)
            {
                Rank = 5;
            }
            else if (Combo < 5500)
            {
                Rank = 6;
            }
            else if (Combo >= 5500)
            {
                Rank = 7;
            }

            if (Rank != RankState)
            {
                RankState = Rank;
                if(Announcer == true)
                {
                    AnnouncerCall(Rank);
                }
            }

            RankSign.rankInstance.SetValue(Rank); //This is the reference to the UIElement class.
        }
}
```

UIElement class:

```
public class RankSign : UIElement
    {
        public Texture2D _rank;
        public static RankSign rankInstance = new RankSign();
        public int _rankID;

        public RankSign()
        {
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/NULL").Value;
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/D").Value;
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/C").Value;
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/B").Value;
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/A").Value;
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/S").Value;
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/SS").Value;
            _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/SSS").Value;
        }


        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (_rankID == 0)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/NULL").Value;
            }
            else if (_rankID == 1)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/D").Value;
            }
            else if (_rankID == 2)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/C").Value;
            }
            else if (_rankID == 3)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/B").Value;
            }
            else if (_rankID == 4)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/A").Value;
            }
            else if (_rankID == 5)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/S").Value;
            }
            else if (_rankID == 6)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/SS").Value;
            }
            else if (_rankID == 7)
            {
                _rank = ModContent.Request<Texture2D>("btTheme/Assets/Textures/SSS").Value;
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(_rank, new Vector2(Main.screenWidth + 20, Main.screenHeight - 20) / 2f, Color.LightGray);
        }

        public void SetValue(int value)
        {
            _rankID = value; //This should change the texture, but it is not doing anything.
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: I changed the code of the *btPlayer* class so that it now uses a reference to a RankSign class object instead of an instance. I also checked that the Update method is called regularly (it is called every game tick, which it should be, so it's fine). Now the *btPLayer* class looks like this (the *RankSign* class remains unchanged, the only difference is that I removed the `public static RankSign rankInstance = new RankSign();`):

```
public class btPlayer : ModPlayer
{
        RankSign RankSign = new RankSign();

        public void RankExchange(int Combo, bool Announcer)
        {
            if (Combo < 170)
            {
                Rank = 0;
            }
            else if (Combo < 300)
            {
                Rank = 1;
            }
            else if (Combo < 500)
            {
                Rank = 2;
            }
            else if (Combo < 1000)
            {
                Rank = 3;
            }
            else if (Combo < 2000)
            {
                Rank = 4;
            }
            else if (Combo < 3500)
            {
                Rank = 5;
            }
            else if (Combo < 5500)
            {
                Rank = 6;
            }
            else
            {
                Rank = 7;
            }

            if (Rank != RankState)
            {
                RankState = Rank;
                if(Announcer == true)
                {
                    AnnouncerCall(Rank);
                }
            }

            RankSign.SetValue(Rank);
        }
}
```

However, I am still unable to change the value of *_rankID* (even when I tried changing the value directly using `RankSign._rankID = Rank;` and not using the method *SetValue()*). The program continuously prints the _rankID value to the game chat and the value does not change.

Comment: You are setting `_rankID`, but `_rank` won't be affected until `Update` is called (and on the correct instance).

Comment: `else if (Combo >= 5500)` is redundant; just an `else` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a static nested `RankSign` member within which you update. This is a single copy within your program. No matter how many instances of `RankSign` you create, you are always updated that one single nested `RankSign` instance.

I'm still not so clear on the bigger picture of what you want to do but you definitely need to change the design a bit.